# HTML & CSS I'm hopeless - Brackets help - divs in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now and I can't seem to work it out.

I am a beginner at CSS and I got told that Brackets might be good for me, seeing as I can enter CSS in the HTML page by pressing Flag + E to open a CSS editor.

Whenever I try and manipulate my 'example' div in CSS, in Brackets, the text goes red so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong.

Here is some code and some images to help understand what I'm talking about (CSS and HTML):

TO VIEW THE IMAGES I think you have to click run code or something (not too sure, I'm a newbie lol)

```html
<a href="http://s1166.photobucket.com/user/JoshMurrayEu/media/number%201_zpsgqlbkio3.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1166.photobucket.com/albums/q619/JoshMurrayEu/number%201_zpsgqlbkio3.png" border="0" alt=" photo number 1_zpsgqlbkio3.png"/></a>

<a href="http://s1166.photobucket.com/user/JoshMurrayEu/media/number%202_zpszwjiiym2.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1166.photobucket.com/albums/q619/JoshMurrayEu/number%202_zpszwjiiym2.png" border="0" alt=" photo number 2_zpszwjiiym2.png"/></a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've tried to **end** the previous ruleset with a `{` instead of a `}`.

This is a syntax error in CSS.

---

(This is a simple typographical error. Consequently, I've marked this as community wiki so upvotes don't get any points and voted to close the question using the typographical error reason).